# why is my javascript not working on my php page?

Tags: javascript, html

I am facing issue with javascript for form validation.
On one of the forms the javascript function is working properly, and when on other form, i am trying to do form validation, but the script does not fire up.. i have tried many times to clear my browser cache and refreshed the page but i am not getting any results. 
I would be thankful if anyone reviews it and help spot the issue.
The following is the function that works on my homepage:

```
 <script>
  function validate()
{
    var uid = document.getElementById("usrname").value;
    var pwd = document.getElementById("passwd").value;
    if (uid == "" || pwd == "") {
    alert("Empty fields not allowed");
        return false;
    }
    else if (uid.length < 4 || uid.length > 20) {
            alert("User ID string length should be between 4 - 20");
            return false;
        }
    else if (pwd.length < 6 || pwd.length >20) {
            alert("Password length should be between 6 - 20");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
}

  </script>
<form name="ulogin" action="login.php" method="post" onSubmit="return validate();">
```

The following validation code on the other page does not run:

```
<script>
  function regval()
    {
     var cname = document.getElementById("name1").value;
     var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
     var phn = document.getElementById("phone").value;
     var addr1 = document.getElementById("addr1").value;
     var addr2 = document.getElementById("addr2").value;
     var city = document.getElementById("city").value;
     var state = document.getElementById("state").value;
     var country = document.getElementById("country").value;
     var uname = document.getElementById("uname").value;
     var pwd = document.getElementById("passwd").value;
     var cnfp = document.getElementById("cnf_passwd").value;
     var secans = document.getElementById("sec_ans").value;
     var regex=/^[0-9]+$/;
     var alphanum=/^[a-z0-9]+$/i;

    if(cname == "" || email == "" || phn == "" || addr1 == "" || addr2 == "" || city == "" || state == "" || state == "" || country == "" || uname == "" || pwd == "" || cnfp == ""|| secans == "") {
         alert("Empty fields not allowed");
         return false;
         } 
    if (cname.length < 3 || cname.length > 20) {
        alert("Name length should be between 4-20 characters.");
        return false;
        } 
    if (email.length < 10 || email.length > 50 ) {
        alert("email length should be between 10-50 characters.");
        return false;
        } 
    if (phn.length < 7 || phn.length > 11 ) {
        alert("check phone number length.");
        return false;
        } 
        else if (!phn.match(regex)) {
         alert("Please check inputs, only numbers are allowed.!");
         return false;
        }

    if (city.toLowerCase() != "surat" || state.toLowerCase() != "gujarat" || country.toLowerCase() != "india") {
        alert("Sorry, we only serve in surat currently at the moment..!!");
        return false;
        } 
    if (uname.length < 4 || uname.length > 20) {
        alert("user name should be between 4 - 20 characters.");
        return false;
        } 
        else if (!uname.match(alphanum)) {
           alert("only characters A-z 0-9 are allowed.");
           return false
        }

    if (pwd.length < 6 || pwd.length > 30) {
        alert("password length should be between 6 - 30 characters.");
        return false;
        } 
        else if (!pwd.match(alphanum) {
          alert("Only characters A-z 0-9 are allowed.");
          return false;
        } 

    if (pwd != cnfp) {
        alert("the passwords do not match, please check and try again.");
        return false;
        }

    if (secans.length < 5 || secans.length > 20) {
        alert("please check for security answer length. It should be between 5 to 20 characters.");
        return false;
        } 
            return true;
    }
  </script>

<form name="usreg" action="signup.php" method="POST" onSubmit="return regval();">
```

the script tags are in the head tags of my webpage.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check your browser debuging tool.

Comment: I'll bet there's a console error - developer tools will show you.  A breakpoint might make it clear, too.

Answer (score 3):

Missing closing bracket `)` Here `else if (!pwd.match(alphanum) {`

```
if (pwd.length < 6 || pwd.length > 30) {
    alert("password length should be between 6 - 30 characters.");
    return false;
    } 
    else if (!pwd.match(alphanum) {
      alert("Only characters A-z 0-9 are allowed.");
      return false;
    }
```

Should be

```
if (pwd.length < 6 || pwd.length > 30) {
    alert("password length should be between 6 - 30 characters.");
    return false;
    } 
    else if (!pwd.match(alphanum)) {
      alert("Only characters A-z 0-9 are allowed.");
      return false;
    }
```

Note: Always check browser console log for errors.